# How do I compare Durations or Intervals in Luxon?

Tags: javascript, datetime, comparison, luxon

I have an Interval[], and I'd like to know which is the largest interval. I thought that converting them to Durations and then comparing may work, but I can't find appropriate methods in the luxon docs, and Google is getting me nowhere.

How do I compare durations or intervals? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One way is you can convert the date you have to an ISO string and then use `diff` to get the difference.  https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/math?id=diffs.

```
var end = DateTime.fromISO('2017-03-13');
var start = DateTime.fromISO('2017-02-13');

var diffInMonths = end.diff(start, 'months');
diffInMonths.toObject(); //=> { months: 1 }
```

That's the example they show in that documentation.

You can also convert the date to a unix timestamp and subtract them to get a difference, after which you convert it back to a date.

If you didn't know "Luxon" is the improved package of the (now deprecated) "moment" package, that's why the documentation is still using moment.

For any more help than that I'd like more information on what exactly you're struggling with and see what you've already tried.

Comment: Say I have two Intervals - which have a start and and end and can be made into a duration. const duration1 = intervals[0].toDuration() gets me 3 hours, 56 minutes. const duration2 = intervals[1].toDuration() gets me 3 hours, 12 minutes.

How would I compare duration1 to duration2 to get the longer duration? Or can you do it straight from an Interval object?

Comment: You should read through that documentation link I provided you, it has an entire section on "duration math" and shows various examples.  But you can use ````var dur = Duration.fromObject({ months: 4, weeks: 2, days: 6 })```` and you can use ````dur.as('seconds') ```` and you can use ````1 hour = 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds```` depending on what you need and you can easily subtract or compare the durations to find the difference in days/milliseconds/whatever.  You can use something like ````let diff = interval1.diff(interval2, 'hours')````.

Comment: I've already read the docs, as I mentioned in my original question. I'm not seeing how knowing there is a 44 minute difference between two durations is going to tell me which is longer? Unless there is such a thing as a negative duration and it will return one.

Comment: If you do a.diff(b) and get a negative number then a is longer, if you do a b.diff(a) and get a negative number, then b is longer, you can swap their places and see which one is longer.

Answer (score -1):

`yourInterval.length()` will give you the length of the interval in milliseconds. So you need only find the interval with the highest result.